# How to create and save file to Files application (iOS platform)

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I need to create PDF-file (done) and save it to Files application, so user can access it anytime outside of my app. I tried `rn-fetch-blob` and `react-native-fs` packages and they worked fine for Android, but for iOS they can only create files to internal app storage (so files are not created in external storage, i.e. not in iOS Files application).
What options do I have to save my created files to Files application? I know that it is possible, i.g. Slack app allows saving files to Files app.

Comment: I have added the below keys in info.plist but didn't work for me. Which directory you have used to save the downloaded file in iOS's Files application. My functionality is exactly same as yours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to either add the `UISupportsDocumentBrowser` key and set to true, or both the `UIFileSharingEnabled` and `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` keys in your `Info.plist` file

When the user will open a document from your app's Documents directory, through Files app, they would be editing the document in place. The changes are saved to your app's Documents directory.

Refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller) for more.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped. P.S.: I added all keys that you had mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

you can try with `react-native-fs` to save and download in local directory.

> var url = path
> let fileName = path.split("/").pop()
> // console.log('fileName', fileName)
> var ext = this.extention(url);
> ext = "." + ext[0];
> const localFile = `${RNFS.LibraryDirectoryPath}/${fileName}`;
> // console.log('localFile', localFile)
>
> ```
>         const options = {
>             fromUrl: path,
>             toFile: localFile,
>             fileCache: true
>         };
>
>         if (await RNFS.exists(localFile)) {
>             FileViewer.open(localFile, { displayName: this.props.route.params.conversationSubject });
>         } else {
>             await RNFS.downloadFile(options).promise
>                 .then((res) => {
>                     // console.log('res', res)
>                     FileViewer.open(localFile);
>                 })
>                 .then((res) => {
>                     // success
>                     // console.log("success", res);
>                 })
>                 .catch(error => {
>                     // error
>                     console.log("Attachment open error: ", error);
>                 });
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I've added new functionality to react-native-share module to store a file only in `Files` app. It's not merged yet but you can use my fork version.
https://github.com/gevorg94/react-native-share/tree/share-files-app.

Replace `"react-native-share": "X.X.X"` with `"react-native-share": "git+https://github.com/gevorg94/react-native-share.git#share-files-app",`.

You can find usage in PR https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share/pull/681