# how to save file from an iOS react native app to Files folder

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, file, storage

I created a pdf file in my react native app for iOS devices, and also I can open the file in my application because it saved in Documents directory of internal storage of my application, but I want to save the file to Files folder in iOS and open it with other applications, how can I do it?
thank for your attention.

Comment: I also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56356311/how-to-create-and-save-file-to-files-application-ios-platform, but it doesn't help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For IOS you should open share options and save the file to the Files folder. For this you can use 'react-native-share' library. If you are using Expo, use 'expo-share'. Please check below documentation.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sharing

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sharing/